# Avoid RuntimeWarning using where

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I want to apply a function to a `numpy` array, which goes through infinity to arrive at the correct values:

```py
def relu(x):
    odds = x / (1-x)
    lnex = np.log(np.exp(odds) + 1)
    return lnex / (lnex + 1)

x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
np.where(x==1,1,relu(x))
```

correctly computes

```
array([0.40938389, 0.43104202, 0.45833921, 0.49343414, 0.53940413,
       0.60030842, 0.68019731, 0.77923729, 0.88889303, 1.        ])
```

but also issues warnings:

```
3478817693.py:2: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  odds = x / (1-x)
3478817693.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  return lnex / (lnex + 1)
```

**How do I avoid the warnings?**

Please note that performance is of critical importance here, so I would rather avoid creating intermediate arrays.

Comment: `where` can't help, since `relu(x)` is evaluated for all `x`.  You could suppress the warnings.  `ufunc` have a `where` parameter, which in conjunction with the `out` can skip some of the elements.

Comment: Do you plan to use `relu(x)` for x greater than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on [`np.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html), to avoid division by zero. This solution is inspired by @hpaulj's comment.

```
def relu(x):
    odds = np.divide(x, 1-x, out=np.zeros_like(x), where=x!=1)
    lnex = np.log(np.exp(odds) + 1)
    return lnex / (lnex + 1)

x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
np.where(x==1,1,relu(x))
```

Output:

```
array([0.40938389, 0.43104202, 0.45833921, 0.49343414, 0.53940413,
       0.60030842, 0.68019731, 0.77923729, 0.88889303, 1.        ])
```